# Can the Magic Keyboard be used with the USB-C to Lightning cable?

Tags: keyboard, usb

Can the [Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english) be used with the [USB-C to Lightning cable](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205807) *and* have the keyboard actually work as a keyboard (not just charge the internal battery)?

The "Here's what you can do..." mentions said keyboard, but only for charging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can connect it up with the USB-C to Lightning cable and use it as a keyboard.

USB is backwards compatible in this manner with the previous versions of USB. The Lightning port really carries a USB signal for data purposes.

Comment: I just confirmed this still works with the newer Magic Keyboard with Touch ID. I have it paired via Bluetooth with my main computer, but when I plugged it into a different computer with the cable, the Bluetooth connection paused and it worked through the cable instead.